# Disable Hyper-V Server 2016 auto updates

Tags: hyper-v, windows-update

I ran into a strange issue last week.

I have a bunch of Hyper-V 2016 Servers joined to a freshly created Active Directory domain (no GPO is currently configured).

There is one server who's rebooting at random moments, making the VMs running on it unavailable. It's not a critical server, so there's no cluster to back up.

I was wondering why, in the sconfig.cmd tool, the "Windows Update Settings" is set to "Personalised", and why I cannot change it to manual or "Download Only"?

Is there any way to change this? It's annoying to see this server rebooting during production hours and not be able to change the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement to make configuration changes using the "sconfig" tool is to use a user which be member of the Administrators group. Once into the toot you can follow these steps to apply the change:

1. Type "5" and hit Enter.
2. Then type "A" (Automatic), "D" (DownloadOnly), or "M" (Manual) then hit Enter.
3. An Update Settings window will pop up to confirm the setting was changed, click OK.

The tool does not provide an update value of "Personalised", so check that your server is not receiving a customized configuration from other source like domain or local GPOs.

About the reboot events, check it they coincide with update events to be sure this is the root cause for them. Normally updates should be programmed during not office hours.
Check into the server logs to other possible causes for this reboot events, maybe a hardware fault, memory fault, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault and thanks for your answer. Gonna check if some GPO are applied. Do you maybe know what does this "Personalised" mean?

Comment: there is no GPO running on the DC.

Comment: "Personalised" refers to a value customized by the user or by an administrator. That is why I asked you about an existing  GPO. Maybe you installed a server operative system customized image.

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and check about this.